# Map a route to a middleware class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Seems like this should be a straightforward question, but I've been unable to find a solution via Google.

It seems pretty standard that in ASP.NET Core, `IHttpHandler` implementors are replaced by middleware classes. One nicety of the old system was that you could set up an HTTP handler to respond to a route, specified in the web.config.

So, for instance, if my `IHttpHandler` implementor was named `FooHandler`, web.config would contain something like:

```
<location path="foo">
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="FooHandler" path="*" verb="*" type="FooCompany.FooProduct.FooHandler, FooCompany.FooProduct"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Is there a one-to-one replacement for routing like this in ASP.NET Core? How do I do this?

**Edit**: The new middleware class might look something like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FooCompany.FooProduct.Middleware
{
    public class FooMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public FooMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("OK");

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }

    public static class FooMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseFoo(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<FooMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Map extension method of `IApplicationBuilder` like `builder.Map("/path", b => b.UseMiddleware<FooMiddleware>())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Map extension method of IApplicationBuilder like that :

```
public static class FooMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseFoo(this IApplicationBuilder builder, string path)
    {
        return builder.Map(path, b => b.UseMiddleware<FooMiddleware>());
    }
}
```

You can also do it inside your Middleware

```
public class FooMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly PathString _path;

    public FooMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, PathString path)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(path))
        {
            // jump to the next middleware
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }

        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Other than path is not assigned to _path and used afterwards, in .Net Core 3.0 it throws an exception in the extension method: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString' while attempting to activate 'FooMiddleware'. What might be missing?

Comment: At least, I think you can use `app.Use(new FooMiddleware(next, "/mypath").Invoke);`. But I didn't test it on netcroe 3